# Unable to mount persistent volume to Docker container using Rex-Ray and VirtualBox Media storage - "Invalid managed object reference" error

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-volume, emc

I'm trying to mount a data volume to a docker container using the Rex-Ray plugin. I've chosen VirtualBox Media as the storage provider.

The versions I'm using are:

- Docker 1.12.5
- Rex-Ray 0.6.3 with libStorage 0.3.5
- VirtualBox base package 5.1.12

The setup:

- One CentOS 7 VM running in VirtualBox
- Docker 1.12.5 running in the CentOS 7 VM
- Rex-Ray installed and running in the CentOS 7 VM
- Mac OS X 10.12.1 host machine

**On the Mac OS host machine:**

1 . I turn off VirtualBox SOAP API authentication with `VBoxManage setproperty websrvauthlibrary null`

2 . I start the VirtualBox SOAP API with 
`vboxwebsrv -H 0.0.0.0 -v` to allow Rex-Ray to communicate with VirtualBox

**In the CentOS 7 VM I'm doing the following (as root):**

1 . Start Docker with `systemctl start docker`

2 . Create the Rex-Ray `/etc/rexray/config.yml` file:

```
libstorage:
  service: virtualbox
  integration:
    volume:
      operations:
        mount:
          preempt: true
virtualbox:
  endpoint: http://192.168.99.1:18083
  volumePath: /Users/<username>/Volumes
  controllerName: SATA
```

where the `endpoint` is the IP on which the VirtualBox SOAP API runs on the Mac OS X host machine and `volumePath` is an existing folder on the Mac OS X host in which volumes will be stored after creation

This config file follows the same format found in the Dell EMC tutorial on https://github.com/codedellemc/labs/tree/master/setup-virtualbox-dockermachine

3 . Start Rex-Ray service using `rexray start`

4 . Create a 1GB volume with 
`docker volume create -d rexray --name pg_data --opt=size=1`

5 . Attempt to run a Postgres docker container using the official `postgres` image. The `rexray` volume created previously is mounted to the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory in the Postgres container:

`docker run -dit --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --volume-driver=rexray -v pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres`

The container fails to start and I receive the following error

`Error response from daemon: VolumeDriver.Mount: {"Error":"VirtualBox error: Invalid managed object reference """}`

My VirtualBox storage settings are shown in the following image:

[virtualbox storage settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncZQm.png)

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the port count for the SATA controller in the VirtualBox storage settings (as shown in the image linked in the question) is set to 1 by default.

The solution was to change this count to however many volumes you think you're going to mount.

A suggested count is 30 according to the Rex-Ray docs: http://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.3/user-guide/storage-providers/#virtualbox

The following configuration worked for me:

[image: image of VirtualBox storage setting]